# missing custom event in GA4 through Google Analytics Data API v4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We have a website with GA4 and want to set up data collection using Google Analytics Data API v4. We can see all custom events we defined show up Google Analytics UI under Engagement/Events. But when we call https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/ some of them are missing.

To be specific we are running the following to get list of all dimensions and metrics:

```
from google.analytics.data_v1beta import BetaAnalyticsDataClient
from google.analytics.data_v1beta.types import GetMetadataRequest

property_id = "PROPERTY_ID"
client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient()
request = GetMetadataRequest(name=f"properties/{property_id}/metadata")
print(client.get_metadata(request=request))
```

Does anyone know why some events are not showing up with the above code?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I found that only events marked as conversion (Configure/Events) show up in the metadata. But why?

EDIT2:
According to https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/advanced#event-scoped_custom_dimensions `https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1beta/properties/GA4_PROPERTY_ID/metadata` only returns metrics and dimensions. So I guess I need to use something else to retrieve all events?